# Ag-Grid treeData: Possible to hide text next to chevron?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm working on using treeData, but was wondering if it is possible to hide the text next to the chevron.

For example, can I hide the letters from the column in [this table](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-runner/vanilla.php?section=javascript-grid-tree-data&example=filler-nodes&enterprise=1&generated=1&grid=%7B%22theme%22%3A%22ag-theme-balham%22%2C%22noStyle%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22enterprise%22%3A1%7D), and just show the chevron? Maybe using cell renderer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that even without using `cellRenderer`.

Include below `styles` in your component declaration.

```
styles: [`
   ::ng-deep [class^='ag-row-group-indent-'] .ag-group-value {
     display: none;
   }
`]
```

Working plunk: **[Ag-Grid treeData: Possible to hide text next to chevron](https://plnkr.co/edit/UVQ0e0O7MCXNADSQfnxG?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an easy fix within the column def:

```
cellRendererParams: {
    innerRenderer: () => '' 
}
```